# Powerbuilder 12.5 Fileexists on ini file returns false on file that does exist

Tags: powerbuilder, file-exists

I have a FileExists check in a window open event on a Profile.ini file in PB 12.5. (windows 7) and then I use a ProfileString call to read some params from the file. (also in open event) However if I open the window and retrieve some data and then close the window, when I reopen the window FileExists now returns false for my ini file. I suspect the app is still connected to the file which causes FileExists to return false on opens. Is there a way to free up the file after I have populated my vars?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The INI functions like "ProfileString" open and close the ini file automatically.  Do you ever use "FileOpen" on the ini file?  If so, you need to do a "FileClose".

Answer (score 0):

I think what is probably happening is that your application's working directory is changing. For example if you let the user save or open a file and they select a different directory, the application's working directory will change.

One way to fix this is to make sure the folder with the INI file is in the path. I don't recommend that because it's just another thing that can be configured wrong. A better way is to call GetCurrentDirectory either in your application's `open` script or in the startup code of your initial window or your application manager if you're using one. If you're using an application manager you'd store the directory in an instance variable. Otherwise a global variable will work. You can then use this saved directory to reference the INI file with the full path name.

Answer (score 0):

For ini Files use ProfileString, as you do not have to open the File by using Fileopen...

Example:

settings.ini

```
[SETTINGS]
Parameter1=Value1
Parameter2=Value2
```

Usage in PB

```
string ls_parameter
ls_parameter = ProfileString('settings.ini', 'SETTINGS', 'Parameter1', 'none')
```

would return Value1

```
string ls_parameter
ls_parameter = ProfileString('settings.ini', 'SETTINGS', 'Parameter3', 'none')
```

would return none as the Parameter does not exist in the settings.ini file